# How to avoid calculating the arguments to logging functions if log output not required

Tags: c++

I have a static logging class with different loglevels and use of variadic templates.

```
template<typename ... Args>
static void info(Args const& ... args);
```

.....

```
template<typename ... Args>
void Logging::info(Args const& ... args)
{
  if (_e_logLevel >= LogLevel::LogLevel_Info)
  {
    std::ostringstream x_stringBuilder;
    using List= int[];
    (void)List {0, ( (void)(x_stringBuilder << args), 0 ) ...};
    _info(x_stringBuilder.str(),2);
  }
}
```

In some place, there are calls like this:

```
Logging::info("something smells wrong here: ",x_object.buildDebugString());
```

if this is just call once in a .cpp i guess there is no problem, since the template puts the implementation to this file. But if the same semantic was called twice or more, i think there is a jump with the first calculated debugString. Even the logLevel is not reached.
To avoid this, I use some like this:

```
if (Logging::logLevelReached(Logging::LevelInfo()))
{
  Logging::info(px_object->longLongDebugString());
}
```

So the question is, **is there a more elegant way of doing this?**

Comment: I can't quite make out what you're asking?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf:  I think the question is basically "how to avoid calculating the arguments to logging functions if log output not required".

Comment: @MartinBonner thanks, I edited the question to your summary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the better use cases for #define macros.  Something like:

```
#define LOG_INFO(args...)                                   \
    do {                                                    \
        if (Logging::logLevelReached(Logging::LevelInfo())) \
            Loging::info(__VAR_ARGS__);                     \
    } while (0)
```

(Note the use of the `do { ... } while(0)` idiom to create a statement that needs to be termninated with a semicolon).

Usage:

```
LOG_INFO(px_object->longLognDebugString());
```

This doesn't support:

```
LOG_INFO()
```

... but why would you want that?

Comment: perfect, I just didn't know that macros support variable arguments.